# Can you increment a slice in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying out numpy by porting over some code I wrote in matlab/octave. In matlab, I can define the equivalent of a python slice, and then increment it as needed. For example, in my matlab code I have

```
HXx_range = 1:NHXx;
HXy_range = 1:NHXy;

blah blah blah

Hx(HXx_range, HXy_range) = Da(Hx_media(HXx_range, HXy_range)).*Hx(HXx_range, HXy_range) + Db(Hx_media(HXx_range, HXy_range)).*(Ez(HXx_range,HXy_range) -   Ez(HXx_range,**HXy_range+1**));
Hy(HYx_range, HYy_range) = Da(Hy_media(HYx_range, HYy_range)).*Hy(HYx_range, HYy_range) + Db(Hy_media(HYx_range, HYy_range)).*(Ez(**HYx_range+1**,HYy_range) - Ez(HYx_range,HYy_range));
Ez(EZx_range, EZy_range) = Ca(Ez_media(EZx_range, EZy_range)).*Ez(EZx_range, EZy_range) + Cb(Ez_media(EZx_range, EZy_range)).*(Hy(EZx_range,EZy_range) - Hy(**EZx_range-1**,EZy_range) + Hx(EZx_range,**EZy_range-1**) - Hx(EZx_range,EZy_range));
```

The terms in '**'s (like 'HXy_range+1') are they key parts; HXy_range+1 is equal to 2:(NHXy+1). In python, I can define a slice in a similar way:

```
HXx_range = slice(0, NHXx)
```

However, HXx_range+1 gives me an error. Of course, I can just make a new slice for that, but it's not as clean. Is there a way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected behavior of an incremented slice?  Do you increment the start?  The end?  Both?

Comment: The expected behaviors would be the same as in the matlab code: incrementing both -- effectively shifting the slice by the given amount.

Answer (score 3):

If you define your `HXy_range` as a numpy array, then you can increment it as desired. If and when you wish to use it as a slice, you can form `slice(*HXy_range)`:

```
In [26]: HXy_range = np.array([1,10])

In [27]: HXy_range+1
Out[27]: array([ 2, 11])

In [28]: slice(*(HXy_range+1))
Out[30]: slice(2, 11, None)
```

Comment: That's good to know. Dumb question: what does the * in line 28 do?

Comment: The `*` used here is the [Python unpacking operator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Answer (score 1):

No, Python `slice` instances are [immutable](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#index-69). To use standard `slice` instances, you must create a new one each time. Unfortunately, [you can't subclass `slice` either](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2005-December/355836.html).